# Using CASE WHEN THEN to get common values between two condition

Tags: mysql

I need to get profiles of all users having `TIME` difference

1. Less than 90 days: 0
2. More than 90 days: 1
3. Less than 90 but greater than 84: 2

Now I have written a query for the same like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT,FILTERED,TYPE,SEEN,CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  `TIME` ) <= 90 AND DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  `TIME` ) >= 84  THEN 2 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  `TIME` ) <=84 THEN 0
            WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW( ) ,  `TIME` ) >90 THEN 1
            END AS TIME1  FROM newjs.CONTACTS WHERE SENDER='1' AND TYPE IN('A','D','I','E','C') AND  RECEIVER NOT IN('5733000','7277453','9535153','9577787','9649101','99398691','99402429') GROUP BY FILTERED,TYPE,SEEN,TIME1
```

The issue with above code is that the counts included in `TIME1 = 2` are not included in the case where `TIME1 = 0`. I know my code is written in that way, but how can I achieve the desired?

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Couldn't write question completely because something went wrong with network connection. Have a look.

Comment: post sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Say you divide people based on their age into children and adults. And then you decide that you want to have a group teenagers too. If you have just the one column then afterwards if you want to select children, you will have to select people with either the value child or teenager. You can create a new column to identify teenagers, if that's what you need. But one column can't have two values for the same row, which is what you seem to want.

Comment: What's the solution? I know my code is not going to work, but still there must be some workarounds. Even if I want to add a new column, how can I do that?

Comment: You create one column that gives a value of 0 for less than 90 and 1 for more than 90. You create a second column that has the value 1 when the diff is between 84 and 90, maybe null otherwise -- depends what you need to do with it later.